# When does type conversion happen in C

Tags: c, type-conversion, integer-promotion

I have following question: e.g. I have given code:

```
uint8_t a = 0x30;
uint16_t b = a << 8;
```

Will `a` be first shifted and then converted to `uint16_t`? Or will it be converted to `uint16_t` first? Or is this behavior compiler dependent? I'm trying to build a `uint16_t` given lsb and msb separately as `uint8_t`s.

P.S. I didn't know this behavior depended on whether it's C or C++, could someone please tell how it will work in both cases?

Comment: C != C++. First decide which language you're actually using and tag with *only* that language.

Comment: C or C++? They are two very different languages, especially when it comes to semantics.

Comment: does this behaviour depend on whether its c or c++

Comment: @ZhaniBaramidze It's like asking about the some code and then tagging that question as Java and Python. Tag with the language you're using.

Comment: It might. And even if not, picking one language will make it easier to find duplicates or links to references.

Comment: Now when you picked a language, I recommend you [read about implicit conversions in C](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion), especially the section about [*integer promotions*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expression evaluation in C is bottom up in the expression tree, that is in your case `a << 8` is evaluated first (obviously) before being used as initializer. C's type system follows this evaluation, but see below, so the type on the right of the `=` has nothing to do with the type on the left. It is only for the initialization that the type itself is adjusted with an implicit conversion.

That said, things are more complicated here for `a << 8` than they look at a first glance, because you chose a type for `a` that is (most likely) a *narrow type*. So on most architectures `uint8_t` as it is narrower than `int` will be promoted to that in any arithmetic expression.

So here in your case that would give you an `int`, thus the left shift with `8` works well, and then the `int` is converted to `uint16_t`.

Had you chosen an constant for `a` with HO bit `1`, the picture would be different. Depending on the architecture (if `int` is 16 bit) this could then shift a `1` into the sign bit and the behavior would be undefined.

All these complicated arguments show, that it is in general not a good idea to do arithmetic with narrow integer types.

Comment: so in any arithmetic operation where operand is narrower then int, its promoted to int before performing the operation?

Comment: and what would happen if int was 16 bits and a was 0xF0? at which point would it go wrong?

Comment: The left shift would shift a 1 into the sign bit, which is not allowed.